# Where to disable NSTimer

Tags: ios, nstimer

I have an app with several ViewControllers. One ViewController has a NSTimer object. Now I have several problems:

1. Where do I disable the timer when the app goes inactive/background? I read that signing the ViewController for the according notifications is the supposed way to do it, but what if the goes inactive while another ViewController is up?
2. Easiest solution is to disable timer in the appdelegate?
3. I want to disable the timer and enable it again when the app has focus again. Whats the best way to do it? Do i have to save the date when the app goes in background and check with the Timers firedate when it gets focus again?

Thx in advance

Comment: What is this timer doing? Should it be running if the associated view isn't on display?

Comment: Yes, its meant to set off an alart after a certian amount of time.

Comment: It seems that view controller is the wrong place to hold this timer then. It has it's own life (in reference to the app). Quick & Dirty way would be to place it in the `appDelegate`. And Xcode template tells you exactly where in `appDelegate` to start and where to invalidate the timers.

Comment: Yeah I thought about that too, but like you indicated, it is kind of an ugly approach to put it in the appDelegate. You are right about the timer being at the wrong place, the thing is the right place would be some kind of 'central manager' instance which for some reason seems to be untypical in ios design (have not seen such in any of the apple example code)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`NSTimer` may not be the right solution to this problem. You have already identified a number of issues, but what if the user closes the app?

Look at using `UILocalNotification` instead. When the notification fires, if your app is closed then the system will display the notification message. If the app is open, your app delegate will get a callback (`application:didReceiveLocalNotification:`) that you can use to update your UI appropriately.

Comment: I agree, using notifications is probably the way to go. Thx a bunch!

Answer (score 1):

Simply you just create your NSTimer instance variable in app delegate and access into your controller and when your application call `- (void)applicationWillResignActive:(UIApplication *)application` just invalidate your timer and save the current NSDate object into your NSUserdefault

Answer (score 1):

Set a flag in `NSUserDefaults` to mark if the timer is active or not.
Then in the method `applicationDidEnterBackground:` invalidate the timer.
And in the method `applicationWillEnterForeground:` start the timer again.
It worked for me.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

The [documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/UIApplicationDelegate_Protocol/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/intfm/UIApplicationDelegate/applicationWillResignActive%3a) states that disabling timers should be done in

```
- (void)applicationWillResignActive:(UIApplication *)application
```

> You should use this method to pause ongoing tasks, **disable timers**,
>   and throttle down OpenGL ES frame rates.

Invalidating timers should be done in

```
- (void)applicationWillTerminate:(UIApplication *)application
```

> You should use this method to perform any final clean-up tasks for
>   your app, such as freeing shared resources, saving user data, and
>   **invalidating timers**.

Restarting the timer should be done in

```
- (void)applicationDidBecomeActive:(UIApplication *)application
```

> For example, you could use it to **restart timers** or throttle up OpenGL
>   ES frame rates.